# Using Obj-C class from Java, is there a way?

Tags: java, android, objective-c, class

I'm working on a project that requires me to run this code in java, but for a brief part of the code I want to access a class that is written in Objective-C.  I want to pass parameters through the class then retrieve the data back into my Java file.

So to try to explain it clearer.  My Java code needs to be able to access an Objective C file and retrieve data that I can implement in Java.  My current IDE is eclipse, because I need to do this for android.  Is there any possible way to make this work?

Comment: Hmm... seems like you're just trying to run some Objective-C methods in Java/Android. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, have you ever implemented something like this or know how to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Rococoa, http://code.google.com/p/rococoa/, or you can use JNI

Here is a similar question with answer: [Wrapping an existing application with JNI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1670859/wrapping-an-existing-application-with-jni)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at JIGS, the Java Interface to GNUStep. http://www.gnustep.it/jigs/